# Как принять ветку через pull request?

Tags: github

Как принять другую ветку (adaptive например) через pull request без мержа в master? Нужно предварительно тоже создавать adaptive, что бы в неё отправляли pull request из аналогичной ветки?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете выбрать ветку, которая будет считаться базой  (т.е. GitHub предложит туда внести изменения) для PR прямо под заголовком "Open a pull request".

[image: пример выбора веток для pull request]

Названия веток совпадать не обязаны; при необходимости есть возможность сделать PR даже в пределах одного репозитория.

После того, как вы отправите запрос на внесение изменений, и если возможно автоматическое слияние, владелец репозитория сможет выбрать из трёх альтернатив: merge, squash, rebase. Наличие этого выбора настраивается на вкладке "Settings".

Comment: т.е. если я приму ветку, которой у меня нет - она не появится у меня? PR можно принимать только в существующие ветки?

Comment: Ну судя по всему, PR можно _сделать_ только в существующие ветки. Это решает автор изменений. Впрочем, вы можете вручную сами сделать любые изменения ваших ветках. Например, если кто-то сделал для вас PR, вы можете скачать заплату, добавив суффикс `.patch` к адресу PR, и затем применить его на нужной ветке командой `git am` из консоли.